# How to split the columns when grouping by

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Example]

The pic's sql is:

```
SELECT pv_nwgp_provider.network_group_id,
       pv_provider.is_facility,
       COUNT(pv_nwgp_provider.provider_id) AS totalCount
FROM pv_nwgp_provider, pv_provider
WHERE     pv_nwgp_provider.provider_id = pv_provider.provider_id
      AND pv_nwgp_provider.network_group_id = 3
GROUP BY pv_nwgp_provider.network_group_id, pv_provider.is_facility
LIMIT 1000
```

what should I do to make the resut is like :

```
network_group_id   Y     N
     3            811   9924
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java.  I have untagged appropriately.

Comment: I view the question, I knew what to do now. Thanks!